# Using variables from Autoloaded files in PHP

Tags: php

I have ran into a problem: When I'm using composer's Autoloaded class to autoload a file, I can not use variables defined within that file anywhere else in my project. But when I'm manually including the file with "require xxx.php" function, the variables are present.

Can anyone explain why and how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to provide a code sample that demonstrates this. It doesn't make a lot of sense as is.

Comment: Can you supply an example of a an autoloaded file which defines variables intended to be used in global scope? That is pretty uncommon.  Basically, the file won't be loaded until composer loads it on-demand, so there may be a solution in the form of instantiating some class in that file, but that is at best a hack.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski how about a config file? In Laravel you can just do `$config = [ ... ];` in config files and the autoloader (admittedly with a little more finesse) takes that and makes it accessible

Comment: @Joe Pretty sure those aren't autoloaded. Or to be more precise...they are loaded automatically but not by the autoload system which IIUC only loads files when a class definition is missing.

Comment: @Joe Config files defining `$config` in global scope? There must be some other architecture then that already knows how to read them.

Comment: Using a variable doesn't trigger the autoloader (thank heavens), it merely creates an un-initialized variable (which actually is initialized to `null`, by default)

Comment: Ah, sorry - not being quite specific enough with terms (been doing heavy stuff today and I'm fried). It's accessed via a method (eg. `Config::get('...')` which loads the `$config` into function scope, not global scope. Different to `new UndefinedClass` autoloading, but the `Config::get` uses similar stuff. TL;DR, it's just an example of why he might want it. He still wants it, even if my example isn't perfect :-)

Comment: Yes,I am using this functionality to get my $config array from the config file. I didn't know that using a variable wouldn't trigger the autoloader.
Thanks a lot!